# Finding the largest $c$ such that $4.7(x-c) = 9-\frac12x^2$ has a real solution $x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, quadratics

Suppose I'm given the following:

$$4.7(x-c) = 9-\frac12x^2$$

How would I go about determining the largest $c$ such that there exists a solution $x\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Hint. Imagine that you have an equation of the form
$$
Ax^2 + Bx +C = 0
$$
When does it have a solution in $x\in\mathbb{R}$ ? 
Now, use this information to solve the problem. You can write $A,B$ and $C$ in terms of the numbers given in the equation.

Comment: If $c$ was given, you would be able to solve that particular equation and see if it had solutions (discriminant $\ge 0$). Now, $c$ is not given, and the discriminant depends on $c$. When is it $\ge 0$?

Comment: For large $x$, $c\sim\dfrac{x^2}{2\cdot 4.7}$.

Comment: re Matti P.'s comment, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways:

- compute the discriminant of the quadratic trinomial and find the largest $c$ that makes it non-negative;
- express $c$ as a function of $x$, and find the global maximum.

> There is no largest $c$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the determinant, since a cuadratic equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has two exact solutions of the form
$$x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

So, for the solution to be real, $b^2-4ac\geq0$ must be true.
Applying this method to your question

$$4.7x-4.7c=9-\frac{1}{2}x^2\\
\frac{1}{2}x^2+4.7x-4.7c-9=0\\
\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}}_a x^2+\underbrace{4.7}_bx\underbrace{-4.7c-9}_c=0$$
So
$$4.7^2-4\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)(-4.7c-9)\geq0\\
(-2)(-4.7c-9)\geq-4.7^2\\
9.14c+18\geq-4.7^2\\
c\geq\frac{-4.7^2-18}{9.14}$$

From here try determining the largest possible value of c.

Answer (score 0):

If we solve for x
\begin{equation}
4.7(x-c) = 9-(x^2)/2\implies x = \frac{\pm\sqrt{940 c + 4009} - 47}{10}\\
\implies x\in\mathbb{R} \iff c > -\frac{4009}{940}\approx -4.264893617\qquad f(-4.264893617)=-4.7
\end{equation}

This means that there is no upper limit to the value of c, only a lower limit.

If we solve for c

$$c = \frac{5 x^2 + 47x - 90}{47}\qquad f(-4.7\approx -4.264893617$$

All other valid values of c and x are larger.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $ \ 4.7(x-c) \ = \ 9 - \frac12x^2 \ $ can have its solutions (if they exist) interpreted as the intersections of the "downward opening" parabola $ \  y  =  9 - \frac12x^2 \ $ with the line $ \ y \ = \  4.7x - 4.7c \ \ . $  Since the line has a steep positive slope and the parabola is symmetrical about the $ \ y-$axis, there must  be two intersections *at least* for all such lines with $ \ y-$intercepts less than or equal to $ \ 9 \ \ . $  This means that $ \ -4.7·c \ \le \ 9 \ \Rightarrow \  c \ \ge \ -\frac{9}{4.7} \ \ . $  So this already tells us that there is some *minimum* value for $ \ c \ \ , $ but no maximum.

Increasing $ \ c \ $ takes the line "downward and to the right" then, since that shifts its $ \ y-$intercept   *lower*, so we wish to find the value of $ \ c \ $ at which the line becomes merely *tangent* to the parabola. (Beyond that, still smaller values of $ \ c \ $ correspond to lines which do not intersect the parabola at all.)  If we rearrange the "intersection equation" and "complete the square", we obtain
$$ \frac12x^2 \ + \ 4.7x \ - \ (4.7c \ + \ 9) \ \ = \ \ \frac12 · (x^2 \ + \ 9.4x \ + \ 4.7^2) \ - \ \left(4.7c \ + \ 9 \ + \ \frac{4.7^2}{2} \right) \ \   $$
$$ = \ \ \frac12 · (x  \ + \  4.7)^2 \ - \ 4.7·\left( c \ + \ \frac{9}{4.7} \ + \ \frac{4.7}{2} \right) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ . $$
This will only produce a single solution when the sum in parentheses equals zero, hence the line is tangent to the parabola for
$$ c \ = \ -\frac{9}{4.7} \ - \ \frac{4.7}{2} \ \ = \ \ -\frac{18 \ + \ 4.7^2}{9.4} \ \ \approx \ \ -4.265 \ \ . $$
[This is of course equivalent to find the value of $ \ c \ $ for which the discriminant of the quadratic equation is zero.]
Smaller values of $ \ c \ \ , $ as we've said, will leave no intersection between the curves, so we must have $ \ c \ \ge \ -\frac{18 \ + \ 4.7^2}{9.4} \ \ . $

We also see from this calculation that the point of tangency occurs at $ \ \left(-4.7 \ , \ 9 \ - \ \frac{[-4.7]^2}{2}  \approx  -2.045 \right) \   \ $ for the line  $ \ y \ = \  4.7x + \frac{18 \ + \ 4.7^2}{2} \ \approx \  4.7x + 20.05 \ \ . $